# find a string with at least n matching elements

Tags: regex, language-theory

I have a list of numbers that I want to find at least 3 of...
here is an example

I have a large list of numbers in a sql database in the format of (for example)

```
01-02-03-04-05-06
06-08-19-24-25-36
```

etc etc
basically 6 random numbers between 0 and 99.

Now I want to find the strings where at least 3 of a set of given numbers occurs.
For example:

given: 01-02-03-10-11-12
return the strings that have at least 3 of those numbers in them.
eg

```
01-05-06-09-10-12 would match
03-08-10-12-18-22 would match
03-09-12-18-22-38 would not
```

I am thinking that there might be some algorithm or even regular expression that could match this... but my lack of computer science textbook experience is tripping me up I think.

No - this is not a homework question! This is for an actual application!

I am developing in ruby, but any language answer would be appreciated

Comment: In all your examples, the numbers are in ascending order. Is this always the case? If it is, you should have stated so. If not, you should have given a more general example to avoid this kind of generalization. Or, even more fundamentally, are you talking about strings or an arrays that include six numbers?

Comment: Yes, the numbers are always ascending. And I am talking about strings. Ideally I would love to do this on the sql level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a string replacement to replace `-` with `|` to turn `01-02-03-10-11-12` into `01|02|03|10|11|12`.  Then wrap it like this:

```
((01|02|03|10|11|12).*){3}
```

This will find any of the digit pairs, then ignore any number of characters... 3 times.  If it matches, then success.

Comment: Nice! Works! Even if the numbers are out of order. Thanks very much!

Comment: It also matches `01-01-01-01-01-01`, `010203`, `11111111111111111111111111111111khhucer`, and many other strings that don't look anything like your examples.  Will that be a problem?